# Arrays as global in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class project to do with an array of a user-defined object type. All of the functions in my ChemicalData.cpp file (there will eventually be more) need to be able to access this array. So the array in question is in my header file with the "extern" syntax.

```
#include <string>
#include "Chemical.h"

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 2000; 
extern Chemical chemArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

void start();
void arrayMethod(Chemical[]);
```

In my cpp file, I have made the array and called a function.

```
#include "ChemicalData.h"
#include "Chemical.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void start()
{
    Chemical chemArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

    arrayMethod(chemArray);
}

void arrayMethod(Chemical[] chemArray)
{
    Chemical chem1 = Chemical();
    chemArray[i] = chem1;
}
```

Here is my Chemical.h:

```
#include <string>
#if !defined(CHEMICAL_H)
#define CHEMICAL_H
using namespace std;

class Chemical
{ 
private:
    string chem;

public:
    Chemical();
};
#endif
```

And Chemical.cpp for good measure:

```
#include "Chemical.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string chem;

Chemical::Chemical()
{
  chem = "";
}
```

But the compiler throws the error of "undefined reference to 'chemArray'".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am compiling it, so how do I link it?

Comment: Don't put `using namespace std` in header files.

Comment: why shouldn't that be in header files?

Comment: If you put this declaration in your header files, then it will be automatically applied to all the cpp files that include that particular header. This way, you always get all the classes from the `std` namespace imported into the default namespace.

Comment: Since you imply Chemical is going to be a base class with more classes derived from it, you probably want an array of pointers instead of an array of objects.

Answer (score 6):

```
void start()
{
    Chemical chemArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

    arrayMethod(chemArray);
}
```

`chemArray` is local to start function move it out of the function.

```
Chemical chemArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

void start()
{
    arrayMethod(chemArray);
}
```

Side note; globals are bad so you might want to wrap this stuff in a class and make that array an instance member of that class.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put ChemArray is a temp variabla inside the function, extern is used for global variables.
Since every time you enter the function there will be a new chemArray..
Remove it to the outside of the function and it will be fine:

```
Chemical chemArray[ARRAY_SIZE]; 

void start()
{

    arrayMethod(chemArray);
}
```

Comment: Static global variables are only visible to the source file where they are defined.

Comment: slipped there, editted, thank you

Answer (score -1):

can't you put Chemical `chemArray[ARRAY_SIZE]` inside your header file instead? then forward declare?